# Oops, something bad happened

Tags: support, bug

I have been trying for the last half an hour to post a question about wordpress and privacy on Web Applications. All goes smoothly till it comes to time of submitting the question to the site. Once I click human verification it shows me images from google images and asks me to identify some parts. After doing that, it does verify  that I'm human and then I get the oops message. Seems to be a vicious circle with no way out. Can anybody help?

Comment: Not sure why MSE didn't want this.  It could be indicative of a larger problem.  It does seem like you were able to post the question, though.

Comment: yes, but only much much later.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, that generic error indicates something transient and/or something on your end that's the problem.

- Try again later
- Try again with a different browser
- Try again on a different network (if possible)
- Try again with browser extensions/add-on *off*